# Crop div from left and right

Tags: html, css, crop

This is my code:

```
<div style="width: 75px; height: 75px; text-align: center; overflow: hidden;">
    <img src"myimg.png"/>
</div>
```

I want to crop from left and right my image in this div.

[image: But it only crop a part from right]

But it only crop a part from right.

I want to do something like this (which works in IE 8-10 too).

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: But it is already centered?

Comment: your code is insufficient. add the css

Comment: If it possible for you to find size of image, then `css image sprites` is good option for you.

Comment: @MMPP I believe you need to explain a bit more what you really want. Since your edit, you no longer want to "center" the image, is that right? Then what do you need exactly? Also, your screen shots show a cropped area that is much larger than the 75×75 mentioned in your source.

Answer (score 5):

You can keep your HTML as is and make the image's `position:relative` and the position `left:-50%` (or `margin-left:-50%`).

Your HTML:

```
<div id="cropper">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-900-600-3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
#cropper{
    width:450px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img{
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
}
```

[**Here's the demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/HEFv2/)

**EDIT**

---

To accurately center the image in any `div` size, you need to position the image in pixels and not in percentage unless the container is exactly half the size of the image. So the final CSS of an image size of 900x600 pixels would be:

```
img{
    position:relative;
    left:-450px;
    }
```

Comment: Nice trick, but this works only because you made the div exactly half as wide as the image. Any other with for the div and it no longer shows the center part of the image.

Comment: @MrLister that's true. The most accurate method is to use `background-image` but my suggestion is based on the html given.

Comment: @MrLister ...unless you set the position of the image in pixels. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to crop pretty much anything:

```
.crop-left {
  clip-path: inset(0 50px 0 0);
}

.crop-right {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 50px);
}

.crop-top {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 50px 0);
}

.crop-bottom {
  clip-path: inset(50px 0 0 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not set the image as background?

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width: 75px; height: 75px; text-align: center; overflow: hidden;">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mydiv
{ 
    background-image:url('myimg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here this is s small trick to crop a div...
put the div you want to crop inside another div..
set overflow of outer div to hidden
them simply shift the inner div as you want to crop it using margin_left,right,top,down attributes...

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="myDiv" style="overflow:hidden;margin-top:-30px"></div>
</div>
```

Simple :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible with an `<img>`. However, you can use the "CSS Sprite" trick:

```
<div style="width: 75px; height: 75px; text-align: center; overflow: hidden;
    background: url(myimg.png) no-repeat center center">
</div>
```

No jsFiddle, sorry, as I don't have your image.

Comment: @Connor to have the image crop on all sides, not just the right side. In he OP's question, each of the screenshots represent the whole graphic, while the dimmed areas are supposed to be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a background image to the `div`

**HTML**

```
<div class='myDiv'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myDiv {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: url('myimg.jpg') no-repeat -123px 0px;
}
```

Adjust `-123px` to the correct left offset from where cropping should start.

EDIT: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXWyh/)

Comment: This really works, I'm not kidding. Guys, don't vote an answer down if you haven't tried them. I can say that I answered the question because he is saying that he will **crop a part from right** and not **center the image** . Thanks for understanding. :)

Comment: You're right. If the OP wants to give an offset in pixels, then this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution proposed a few times here for similar questions:http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj

```
/* see demo : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj , to play with and understand */ 
parent {
   line-height:equals to height;
   text-align:center;
}
parent img {
   vertical-align:middle;
   margin:-100%;
}
```

It's about clipping your image.You have that old and usefull CSS rule : clip:rect(); 
http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clip wich has this purpose.

Or using a trick (cause you enjoy to play with CSS) to reduce virtually image zize to null, so it centers horizontally and vertically no matters it's real size.
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj

Answer (score -1):

There are more possible solutions for this:
Using a container div and applying negative positioning on the image. Or you can set the image as the background of div which makes you able to use background-position for example.

Comment: Applying positioning only works if the size of the image is known.

Comment: He can still apply "top center".

Comment: Not quite. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TFCCQ/ It is not centered. Can you fix that using only positioning in %?

Comment: I hate that SO allows comments to be edited after a reply is already given.

Answer (score -2):

Below is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ARRuR/1/)** link as per your requirement, which work in ie.

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>

.mainDiv {
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:700px;
    height:500px;
    text-align:center;
}
.mainDiv .green {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

It's possible with image and any element, css positioning, provided that you know the width of the image.
Add `position:relative` to the div, and `position:absolute` on the image together with half the width of the image in a `left:-204px;top:0;`.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctXcJ/2/

Comment: my image has fluid width, it is in a php loop

Comment: Ok? echo the image width with PHP and divide it by 2 then. I illustrated a technique that it IS possible with an image as other upvoted answers suggested it was not.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not downvoted you... I don't know who was downvoted these answers...

Comment: It does not matter, I'm not here for any -fame :). Anyhow, provided that you want to use an image-tag the negative offset solution is the way yo go, but then you need to know the image width. The background CSS solution is also an alternative where you don't have to know the image width.

Answer (score -3):

try `margin: 0 auto;` instead of `text-align`.